# Prolog: reverse([], A) vs reverse(A, [])

Tags: prolog

I can't make any sense out of this: If I give Prolog `reverse([], A).` it works fine, if I give it `reverse(A, []).` and answer `;` on first suggestion it hangs!

Why? (Same result for both GNU Prolog and SICStus Prolog!)

```
aioobe@r60:~$ prolog
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz
| ?- reverse([], A).

A = []

yes
| ?- reverse(A, []).

A = [] ? ;

Fatal Error: global stack overflow (size: 32768 Kb,
environment variable used: GLOBALSZ)

aioobe@r60:~$
```

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old, but just to update: this is fixed in a later version of `gprolog`. I am running version 1.4.2 and the behavior of reverse acts just as their manual says. Both cases instantiate `A` successfully to `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an overzealous optimization for a built-in predicate to me.  The same problem occurs regardless of the contents of the list in the second argument.  Based on the GProlog manual this is a bug.  Notice that the [template for `reverse`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog043.html#toc161) is

```
reverse(?list, ?list)
```

And further that [`?`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog018.html) means "the argument can be instantiated or a variable."

SWI-Prolog version 5.6.64 gives the expected result.

```
?- reverse([], A).
A = [].

?- reverse(A, []).
A = [] ;
false.
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bug. In YAP 6.0.5 the same behaviour. Documentation says `reverse(+List, ?Reversed)`.

Comment: Interesting.  At the very least the GProlog documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My reverse did the same, because I assumed argument 1 would be instantiated (i.e. reverse(+,?), as above), knowing that my Prolog would index on it.
Here:

```
reverse(L, R) :- reverse_1(L, [], R).

reverse_1([], X, X).      % <-- doesn't loop on unbound arg #1 if this clause cuts
reverse_1([A|As], X, R) :-
   reverse_1(As, [A|X], R).
```

Comment: So this one works better you say? Or does this definition loop?